# Access denied for user 'test'@'ip'(using password: YES)

Tags: mysql

I have found many posts for this error, tried everything but still getting same error.I am trying to connect to mysql on ubuntu server from my remote app and mysql client. Let me post whatever steps I have taken already :

1. Stop the firewall on ubuntu server : iptables -F. Also tried with sudo service ufw stop.
2. Commented "bind-address" in /etc/mysql/my.cnf and restarted mysql.
3. Added user in mysql : CREATE USER 'test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'testpwd';
4. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'testpwd'  WITH GRANT OPTION;
5. FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
6. I can see the entry of new user by "Select host, user from mysql.user";
7. restarted mysql again. Still the same error!
8. Now I thought maybe there is some problem still with firewall, so added :iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
   Problem still persist.

Comment: can you connect locally?

Comment: try to connect on mysql on the server in the command line (mysql -u root -p yourdatabase). If it doesn't work, you can try 'sudo service mysql stop', then 'sudo service mysql start'. If the stop doesn't work, pkill mysql several times and retstart 'sudo service mysql start'. Got that problem on ubuntu.

Comment: That error will only come up if the user and password combo is denied generally due to 1: User / password incorrect 2. Host does not have privileges to login as that user. Your remote server is able to connect to the server but not authenticate.

Comment: Yes I can connect it locally : sudo mysql -u test -p but still same error when I connect through mysql client

Comment: @matt I can ping that server from my remote machine. Not sure about other privileges though.

Comment: Try `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'testpwd' WITH GRANT OPTION;` and flush the privileges again.

Comment: I think this is perfectly relevant and doesn't deserve to be closed.  OP has clearly made an effort, and this is the kind of problem we see all the time., as seen by all the suggestions here in the comments.

Comment: @matt no luck still.

Comment: @Alex Thanks ,yea I am trying to solve this from over 2 days now!

Comment: @a3765910 too bad this never was resolved. I'm now, almost five years later, having the same issue.

Comment: @FatAlbert the story ended in a funny way! We were using in-house servers without aircon in the mid summer and it blew-up.

Comment: @a3765910 that's one way to solve the problem 

Answer (score 8):

"Access denied for user 'test'@'ip'(using password: YES)" is a MySQL error.

This means that at the network level **everything is working**, because to be denied access **as a given user**, the server *must have understood which user you were trying to connect as*. So network, firewall, routing, and so on and so forth, **must all be working**; the server must be listening, etc..

The problem lies "simply" in the *authentication*.

Try connecting locally to the database (to override the authentication) and inspect the privilege table:

```
USE mysql;
SELECT User, Host, Password from user WHERE User = 'test';
```

and remember that the line you're interested in is the one mentioning the IP (since the error message **specifies the IP**, and *not* the host name - in which case, it could have been a DNS problem; the host name is *the hostname that the server believes you are coming from*, not the hostname you are really coming from).

The user/host matching goes [from **more specific** to **less specific**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connection-access.html). So if you already had:

```
user      host     password
test      1.2.3.4  foo
```

and ran,

```
GRANT... TO test@'%' ... PASSWORD bar
```

...this grant would work from everywhere **except** 1.2.3.4, where the password would remain 'foo'.

From the manual (link above):

> *The server uses sorting rules that order rows with the most-specific
>   Host values first. Literal host names and IP addresses are the most
>   specific. (The specificity of a literal IP address is not affected by
>   whether it has a netmask, so 192.168.1.13 and
>   192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 are considered equally specific.) The pattern '%' means “any host” and is least specific. The empty string
>   '' also means “any host” but sorts after '%'. Rows with the same Host
>   value are ordered with the most-specific User values first (a blank
>   User value means “any user” and is least specific). For rows with
>   equally-specific Host and User values, the order is indeterminate.*

You might be forced to do

```
USE mysql;
DELETE FROM user WHERE User = 'test';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'test'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

to ensure that there're no spurious lines in the grant table referring to the user 'test'.

(Also, the GRANT should be, I think,

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.*
```

)

---

## Security doubt (unrelated to the answer)

The manual above says: **The specificity of a literal IP address is not affected by whether it has a netmask, so 192.168.1.13 and  192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 are considered equally specific**.

Now at a very first glance `127.0.0.1/0.0.0.0` seems very specific (and harmless) for *localhost*. The netmask, if I'm not mistaken, ensures that it is equivalent to `%`, *except that it is incredibly specific and will run first*. Therefore

```
test     bar         %           
test     localfoo    127.0.0.1/0.0.0.0
```

means that the password for `test` from anywhere it's not "bar" at all, but it is "localfoo".

No one would insert such a grant by mistake, but there's mistake and *mistake*.

Comment: also like to add in `my.cnt` make sure you have old_passwords turned on as you might have a old mysql client which doesn't allow certain new passwords hashes to connect :) `# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1`

Comment: Should I try deleting the multiple entry of single user in mysql.user table? Since I was trying I can find multiple entry of user "test" for different host including "%"

Comment: I would delete all the users expect for `root` and re-create the ones you need properly.

Comment: @Iserni I have tried now with deleting all the users except root ,created a fresh user but still problem persists

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting with the right server? This is way weird. What happens if you **stop** the mysql server temporarily and try to connect? Does it say connection refused?

Comment: @Iserni Yes I tried it, when I stop mysql I get unable to connect error, I am sure it has to be a problem at OS level. I am not much familiar to ubuntu.

Comment: No, it is not at the OS level - if the OS prevented you from connecting, you'd get a socket error, not an authentication error. What version is the client, and what the server? Can you search "password" in your `my.cnf`? I'm going out on a limb, but maybe you have OldPassword support active. Unlikely in the extreme, but so is what's happening to you...

Answer (score 0):

First let's check - it's network/firewall problem or not.
Start MySql server with --skip-grant-tables , then try to connect to it.

Comment: Yes just did, but still no luck. I think so I have tried a lot. I guess there might be some other issue altogether. I am not a network guy so any suggestions here?

Comment: In fact if you can connect as root locally, and still failed to connect from remote PC to non-pass protected DB, may be you have some my.cnf issues, such as skip-networking option?

Comment: I do not have skip-networking option in my my.cnf , I have "bind-address" parameter which I commented out

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on my .net core console app, when trying to connect to my MariaDb database.
I finally find that the uid in my connectionstring was not correct because it is case sensitive!
Even if I felt quite stupid, it might help...