# Access denied for user - CLOUD SQL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to connect a springboot project to a CLOUD SQL db and i go the error :

> com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException: Access denied for user 'user'@'IP' (using password: YES).

and

> SQL State  : 08001
>   Error Code : 0
>   Message    : Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

I tried to connect to this CloudSQL instance using the mysql-client with the same user ans passsword and it works perfectly.

Here is the springboot conf i'm using:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://INSTANCE_IP/DB_NAME?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
    username: USERNAME
    password: PASSWORD
```

Has anyone an idea of what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access denied for user 'test'@'ip'(using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845130/access-denied-for-user-testipusing-password-yes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a MySQL exception that occurs when you have the wrong username or password. There is a detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845130/access-denied-for-user-testipusing-password-yes).

I would also suggest checking out the [Cloud SQL JDBC Socket Factory](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory), which can help Java users connect to Cloud SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Socket Factory is working pretty well. I tried to re-create a CloudSQL instance with Terraform and this time i added directly the DB via Terraform and it worked well (I used to add the DB by hand in the gcp console).