# Go Daday Hosting CPanel code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR', errno: 1045, sqlState: '28000', stack: 'Error: Access denied for user 'UserName'@'IP address'

Tags: mysql, node.js, cpanel, godaddy-api

**Kind Request before marking it as duplicate read full question.**

**Error** :-  'Access denied for user 'Test_UG'@'88.81.84.184' (using password: YES)', code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR', errno: 1045, sqlState: '28000', stack: 'Error: Access denied for user 'Test_UG'@'88.…Trampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)'

**Software/Application/Program used for** – Visual Code, Node.js, PHP, MySQL

**Hosting Used** – Go daddy, Cpanel

**Purpose of Program** – Making Telegram Bot, MySQL being used for storing data

**Was it working on Local Machine ?** – Yes it was working on local machine using Wamp Server.

**Change made** – only changed MySQL connection details

**Solution tried** – Tested with full access new DB, User & Password, also tested with old user which is created 2-3 days ago. Tried many solutions from stack overflow few of them are below

[MySQL: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES) except root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353402/mysql-access-denied-for-user-testlocalhost-using-password-yes-except-ro)

[Access denied for user 'test'@'ip'(using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845130/access-denied-for-user-testipusing-password-yes)

[Access Denied for User 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) - No Privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975120/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-no-privileges)

**Node.js code –**

```
// Create a MySQL pool
const dbConnect =({
    host: 'xyz.com',
    user: 'Test_UG',
    password: 'Xyz@1122!',
    database: 'xyz_bot',
  });

// Function to store user messages in the database
async function storeMsg(msg) {
   
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection(dbConnect);

    try {
        await connection.execute('INSERT INTO chat_details (username, user_id, msg_date, token_name, token_amount, msg) VALUES (?, ?, NOW(), ?, ?, ?)',
            [msg.from.username, msg.chat.id, getRandomToken(), getTokenAmount(0.001, 0.2), msg.text]);

        console.log('User message stored in the database.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Database error:', error);
    } finally {
        connection.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you connect to your database instance on Godaddy and run `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'Test_UG'@'%'` and confirm the user exists and has privilege to use database `xyz_bot`?

Comment: @BillKarwin - Yes all privilege are givien to user... i executed given command but giving below error `#1044 - Access denied for user 'cpses_oi7as6pfov'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'`

Comment: This seems like a technical support call to Godaddy is required.

Comment: @BillKarwin do you know how to flush on Godaddy ?

Comment: I have never used Godaddy, but I do know it's not necessary to FLUSH PRIVILEGES after using CREATE USER or GRANT. You only need to flush privileges if you use INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE directly on system tables. But it seems you don't have privilege to do that anyway, so I assume you don't need to flush privileges.

Comment: @BillKarwin thank you for help.. I connected with Technical Support and Issue got resolved... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I connected with Go Daddy technical support team they gave below solution...

Go to --> CPannel --> Database --> Remote MySQL

[image]

Input your IP address/localhost address in my case it is `88.81.84.184` and click on Add Host.

[image]

It take 5 to 90 min update.